# rbind is changing a constant number of one of my columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to make a matrix form a dataframe, everything is working perfect but when I use rbind a constant number that I have in one of my columns change.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
       CHR  POS    Fd     FdDenom
  1    10   3809  0.0000  0.0000 
  2    10   5673 -0.2500  0.0000
  3    10   5847  0.0000  0.5000
 ...
```

And is named FS_10

On than I am running the next for loop

```
 table10 <-c()
 a <- 0
 for(i in 1:round((nrow(Fs_10)/50))) {
 window <- Fs_4[a:c(a+50),]
 a<- a+50 
 a1 <- sum(window$FdNum)
 a2 <- sum(window$FdDenom)
 Result <- a1/a2
 start <- window[1,]
 end <-window[50,]
 middle <- (start[,2]+end[,2])/2
 table10 <- rbind(table10,c(window[1,1], start[,2], end[,2], end[,2]-start[,2], middle, Result))
}
```

My output look like this:

```
     V1    V2       V3        V4          V5           V6
  1   2     3869   624096   620287      313952.5     0.029411765
 50   2   624096   624694      598      624395.0     0.500000000
100   2   624714   625470      756      625092.0     0.205128205
```

I expect in column V1 the number 10, but I am having 2, I have change several things and the 2 is still there instead the 10. Do you know what is happening?

A simplified version of the porblem is:

```
  rbind(c(start[,1], start[,2], end[,2]), c(start[,1], start[,2], end[,2]))
```

Where start is:

```
        CHR       POS FdNum FdDenom
240938  10  148990666  0.25    0.25
```

And end is:

```
        CHR       POS FdNum FdDenom
240987  10 149534407  -0.5       0
```

I have this:

```
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
   [1,]    2 148990666 149534407
   [2,]    2 148990666 149534407
```

Again 2 instead 10

Unsing this:

```
  rbind(list(inicio[,1], inicio[,2], fin[,2]), list(inicio[,1], inicio[,2], fin[,2]))
```

I have this:

```
      [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     
 [1,] factor,1 148990666 149534407
 [2,] factor,1 148990666 149534407
```

Do you know which is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are creating a `list`

Comment: Thanks, but why the 10 is changing to 2 in all the rows?

Comment: CHR is a factor and not numeric.  When the column is converted to a matrix all values need to be the same data type and thus 10 is converted to its factor value.  To covert from value to numeric use `as.numeric(as.character(start$CHR))`

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie programming in R, I thought that I was creating a matrix but akrun is right, I was creating a list. My solution was to create instead a dataframe substituting the las line of my for loop with this:

```
  tabla10 <- rbind(tabla10,data.frame(window[1,c(1,2)], start[,2], end[,2], end[,2]-start[,2], meddle, Result))
```

However I still do not understand why the 10 was turning in to 2, I'll study more about this.

Thanks